# Please clarify, what is the difference between "Clan" and "Family"? Migrated from History beta

Tags: word-meaning

I would be grateful if there are any supporters [about my question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51046/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-clan-and-family) at History.

History recommended and put on hold because the question should be rather asked either at ELU o ELL.

I appreciate any answer in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both refer to family relationships, though depending on cultural and historical context clan may refer to something broader.

When taking *clan* to mean strictly a group of people related by blood or marriage, the same meaning as *family*, it would tend to connote a much more extended relationship group than *family*. *Family* can mean something as broad, but usually only does so if context indicates it or you use extra words.

There are, I understand, historical/cultural contexts where it actually meant a family plus other families who were loyal to them.